# How to display an image field next to the title on the profile pages?

Tags: 7, theming, users

My users have an image field, called 'Avatar', that's displayed as an icon. I can easily add it to the users' profile page in the content section, but now I'd like to show it next to the title (the default one prints the username).

[image: Title on the profile page.]

As I didn't try to do this before, I surfed around the internet for a while. It seems that lots of similar requests were solved by a template file. Therefore, my plan was to add a `user-profile.tpl.php`, copy all the code from `page.tpl.php` to it and add

```
<?php
print render($user_profile['field_avatar']);
?>
```

before the title.

I'm not sure whether this might work. Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Greatly thanks to @Michiel, I've been able to get this working with the following code:

```
function MYMODULE_process_page(&$vars, $hook) {
 if(arg(0) == 'user'){
  $user = user_load(arg(1));
  $image = array(
   '#theme'  => 'image',
   '#path'   => file_create_url($user->field_avatar['und'][0]['uri']),
   '#attributes' => array('class' => 'avatar_title'),
  );

  $vars['title'] = render($image) . $vars['title'];
 }
}
```

It's important not to use `global $user` instead of `user_load(arg(1))`, because the custom user fields aren't loaded in the first case (see: http://davidsonj.com/blog/global-user-vs-userload). Therefore, you'll get the error that `field_avatar` is undefined.

Thanks to the `avatar_title` CSS class, you can theme the image any further to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

The use of the template is solid guess. However, you're using the wrong template. The template you suggesting isn't based on the `page.tpl.php` page. The output of the `user-profile.tpl.php` page, will end up in the `$content` section of your page template. 
You should try to use a different approach.

How about a preprocess function? It will intercept the rendering of the variables and by so, you can alter them. If you want to change the title of your user-profile page, I'ld go with something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_process_page().
 */
function mymodule_process_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  // Load the global user object
  global $user;

  // Check if it's the userpage and the current user, depending on URL
  if ((arg(0) === 'user') && (arg(1) === $user->uid)) {
      $vars['title'] .= ' ' . $user->avatar[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
  }
}
```

Above preprocess function should be placed in your preprocess folder of your theme or the `template.php`.
It will extend the existing title with your extra fieldvalue.

There is only one drawback on this implementation. If you have a page with a path like `/user/overview`, the title will change too. Every URL with `user` as first argument and a UID as second, will be altered...

Goodluck!

***EDIT:***
Try this please and let me know how it went:

```
/**
  * Implements hook_process_page().
  */
function mymodule_process_page(&$vars, $hook) {
    // Load the global user object
    global $user;

    $image = array(
      '#theme'  => 'image',
      '#path'   => file_create_url($user->field_avatar[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri']),
      '#width'  => 20,
      '#height' => 20,
    );

    if ((arg(0) === 'user') && (arg(1) === $user->uid)) {
      $vars['title'] = render($image) . $vars['title'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Michiel! I've added your code to my theme's `template.php` file, but it returns three errors: `$field_avatar` (I changed the field name to the correct one), 'variable' and 'title' are undefined. What's going wrong?

Comment: Most likely a typo in the declaration of your variables. Can you provide a pastebin with some of your code?

Comment: Do you mean I should provide the values for 'user' and 'title'? The image should be added to every profile page and the title should stay the same. Is this what your code does? I don't fully understand it, because I've never used `hook_process_page` before.

Comment: So, you want to render an image before the title? And on every user page?

Comment: Can you provide a `dpm` of your user object in your question or via pastebin? I'll try my best to get you started!

Comment: Yes, as I explained in my question, the image should be displayed on every profile page. The picture is unique to the user, because it's a user field.

Comment: Here you go. Try to render the image the proper way, like I do and you'll be good to go according to the newest Drupal standards!

Comment: @Jeroen, please don't use `'und'` in your field declaration... It's not the way to display things. Are you sure your avatar field is a part of the `$user` object? Of is it from a `$field`?

Comment: An error is thrown when I use `[LANGUAGE_NONE]`, so that's why I changed it in your code. I've been able to fix the problem and added it as a new answer. I'll upvote yours for your help. :)

Comment: Hmm... I don't see what's any different then my solution... You don't have to load the user object as it is available in `global $user`...

Comment: The custom user fields aren't loaded with `global $user`, so that's why your code doesn't work. I found an example about this issue at http://davidsonj.com/blog/global-user-vs-userload.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure the file to copy is modules/user/user-profile.tpl.php and put it in your theme folder https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user-profile.tpl.php/7 and make the changes in that.

Comment: When I first read this answer I thought that was the correct file indeed, but now that I've opened it, it only contains the code `print render($user_profile);`. That doesn't help me any further...